# Switch Legend Order

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have been making a chart that plots the energy levels of the hydrogen atom and while technically everything shown in the first graph attached is correct I was trying to switch the order of the legend on the right so that the red line is on the bottom and still labeled as n=1. When I switch the range on the legend it makes the graph look like the second picture where n=1 is on the bottom but none of the colors correspond correctly. Any suggestions for how to change the order while keeping the order correct?
My code is as follows

```
import numpy
import math
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
colors = ['#e6194b', '#3cb44b', '#ffe119', '#4363d8', '#f58231', '#911eb4', '#46f0f0', '#f032e6', '#bcf60c', '#fabebe', '#008080', '#e6beff', '#9a6324', '#fffac8', '#800000', '#aaffc3', '#808000', '#ffd8b1', '#000075', '#808080', '#ffffff', '#000000']
#Values the user can edit
n_int = 6 #The inital energy level (must be greater than n_final)
n_final = 5 #The final energy level 
n_max = 11 #This is the highest energy level you want to look at plus 1 (ie: for energy levels 1-10 "n" would be 11)

# Energy level diagram for the Hydrogen Atom (all energy levels)
m_e = 9.1093837015* 10 ** -31 # kg
e = 1.602176634* 10 ** -19 # C
vp = 1.113* 10 ** -10 # C^2 / Jm
h = 6.62607015 * 10 ** -34 # J*s
h_bar = h/(2 * math.pi)  
n_min = 1
n = numpy.linspace(n_min, n_max, n_max-n_min)

#Equation broken down
p1 = m_e * e **4
p2 = 2 * vp ** 2 
p3 = h_bar ** 2
p4 = n ** 2
p5 = p2*p3*p4
e_lv = - p1/p5 #Outputs the values for the energy levels you inputed

max_bound = -numpy.log10(numpy.abs(y_big))
e_lv_math = -numpy.log10(numpy.abs(e_lv_i))
e_lv_math2 = -numpy.log10(numpy.abs(e_lv_f))
d_e_math = e_lv_math2-e_lv_math

inc = 0
for big_int in e_lv:
    x_big = range(0,n_max)
    y_big = [big_int]*n_max
    plt.plot(x_big, -numpy.log10(numpy.abs(y_big)), color = colors[inc])
    inc+=1
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])
    plt.ylabel('Relative Energy Levels')
    plt.arrow(4.5, e_lv_math, 0, d_e_math, width = 0)
    plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(range(n_max,0,-1), loc="center right", bbox_to_anchor = (1.2,.5), title = "n=")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the red label '1' to be at the bottom of the legend. Why not draw in reverse `for inc, big_int in enumerate(reversed(e_lv))` and apply your colors like `color=colors[len(e_lv)-1-inc]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the invert the order of legend lines and keeping labels as they are, you have to invert the order of legend `handles`.
You should get `handles` and `labels` from the axis where you are plotting:

```
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
```

then pass them to the `legend`, inverting the order of `handles`:

```
ax.legend(handles = handles[::-1], labels = labels)
```

**Example of working code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax[0].plot([0, 1], [1, 1], color = 'red', label = 'line 1')
ax[0].plot([0, 1], [2, 2], color = 'blue', label = 'line 2')
ax[0].plot([0, 1], [3, 3], color = 'gold', label = 'line 3')

ax[0].legend(frameon = True, loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1))

ax[1].plot([0, 1], [1, 1], color = 'red', label = 'line 1')
ax[1].plot([0, 1], [2, 2], color = 'blue', label = 'line 2')
ax[1].plot([0, 1], [3, 3], color = 'gold', label = 'line 3')

handles, labels = ax[1].get_legend_handles_labels()
ax[1].legend(handles = handles[::-1], labels = labels, frameon = True, loc = 'upper left', bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1))

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image]